# double click in submit button to make a function work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a problem with two functions the problem is **should click twice on the button to make a change and should click one time only**

```
const addToBalance = (personId) => {
    userInfo.map((user) => (
        user._id === personId ? setUserGetMoney(user.balance) : ''
    ))
    if (userGetMoney !== 0 && parseInt(inputMoney) !== 0 && parseInt(inputMoney) !== null){
        setUserGetMoney(userGetMoney + parseInt(inputMoney))
        console.log(userGetMoney)
    }
}
```

```
const removeFromBalance = () => {
    const id = params.id;
    userInfo && userInfo.map((user) => (
        user._id === id ?  setUserRemoveMoney(user.balance) : ''
    ))
    if (userRemoveMoney !== 0 && personId && parseInt(inputMoney) !== 0 && parseInt(inputMoney) !== null){
       setUserRemoveMoney(userRemoveMoney - parseInt(inputMoney))
       console.log(userRemoveMoney)
    }
}
```

submit function

```
const onSubmitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addToBalance(personId);
    removeFromBalance();
    if (personId && parseInt(inputMoney) !== 0 && parseInt(inputMoney) !== null){
        postTransactionData();
    }
}
```

```
<button type='submit' onClick={(e) => onSubmitForm(e)}>Submit</button>
```

When I try to click the submit button to execute the two functions `addToBalance` and `removeFromBalance` they don't work but when I click again on the submit button it works I want a solution so that I only click once on the button to make the functions work

the video explains the problem: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18usf6CXOyaDi4Py_VbEeNYdyE5Sl91-T?usp=sharing

Comment: I am not sure, but do you mean you want to prevent double click?

Comment: I will clarify the question, sorry. Yes, I do not want to double-click to execute the action

Comment: @AhmedRadi, can you please edit your question and include running code? That'll make it much more possible for us to be able to assist you.

Comment: I added a video link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18usf6CXOyaDi4Py_VbEeNYdyE5Sl91-T?usp=sharing

Comment: the video link is really worthless.  post a working snippet of what you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting state and expecting that state change to be a: synchronous, and b: available in that render.

There are quite a few resources that get into exactly what's going on, but the important thing to note is that the values within your functions are inside what's known as a closure, and they won't change... ever, they only appear to change because re-rendering re-creates the variables and those will have the new values, but they are by definition different variables each render.

[How To Solve The React Hook Closure Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806541/how-to-solve-the-react-hook-closure-issue)

It fails the first time because your userGetMoney and userRemoveMoney variables are likely set to 0 to start, then the first button click causes them to be set to the current balance. The second button click causes them to be set with the current balance, and then set again with the current balance +/- the inputMoney. And if you change users after the first run, you'd see that something really crazy occurs - it would be setting the new user's money based on what the previous one had.

My recommendation to you is to just use the values you have and pass it around within the function instead of using React State for this.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App({ userId }) {
  const [inputMoney, setInputMoney] = useState("");
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(() => [
    { _id: 1, balance: 200, name: "bob" },
    { _id: 2, balance: 250, name: "joe" },
    { _id: 3, balance: 300, name: "billy" },
  ]);
  const [sendeeId, setSendeeId] = useState('');

  function postTransactionData({ sender, sendee, money }) {
    const updatedSender = { ...sender, balance: sender.balance - money };
    const updatedSendee = { ...sendee, balance: sendee.balance + money };
    if(updatedSender.balance<0){
      // Don't have enought funds!
      return;
    }
    console.log("transaction:", updatedSender, updatedSendee);
    setUserInfo((prev) =>
      prev.map((user) => {
        if (user._id === sender._id) {
          return updatedSender;
        }
        if (user._id === sendee._id) {
          return updatedSendee;
        }
        return user;
      })
    );
  }

  function getUser(personId) {
    return userInfo.find((user) => user._id === personId);
  }

  const onSubmitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const sender = getUser(userId);
    const sendee = getUser(sendeeId);
    const money = parseInt(inputMoney,10);
    if (!sender || !sendee || !money || Number.isNaN(money)) {
      //Invalid transaction
      return;
    }
    postTransactionData({ sender, sendee, money });
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
      <input
        name="money"
        type="number"
        value={inputMoney}
        onChange={(e) => setInputMoney(e.target.value)}
      />
      <select value={sendeeId} onChange={(e) => setSendeeId(+e.target.value)}>
        <option value={''}>Unset</option>
        {userInfo.filter(({_id})=>_id!==userId).map((user) => (
          <option key={user._id} value={user._id}>{user.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App userId={1} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: I appreciate the information and advice you have shared. Thank you very much.
I have one question why use `+` in the `setSendeeId` here `<select value={sendeeId} onChange={(e) => setSendeeId(+e.target.value)}>`

Comment: That's a unary plus operator, which converts the value to a number.

Comment: Thank you, bro, I am very happy with your answer, I think in my code no need to `+` because I am using `ID` as `String`  thank you again <3